# Fancy Box 2 automatically closes divs?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

So I'm using fancybox 2 on a div. But for some reason, when I click the div and fancybox opens, it hides the div (only showing the outline of the wrapper div), and the only way I can get the div back is to reload the page. Anyone else have this problem? If so, how do I fix it?

I searched google all last night and couldn't find anyone who was having this problem. And after reading the [license page](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license) I don't think fancybox 2 supports the `onClose` or `onStart` attributes.

Here's my div

```
<div class='photo'><img class='fancybox' src='images/jpge1.jpg></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('.fancybox).click(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
});
```

Comment: Fancybox2 uses `beforeLoad` and `beforeClose` in place of `onStart` and `onClose` respectively.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So when I close the image in fancybox i'm trying to reopen it by using `'beforeClose':function(){$('.fancybox').show()},` as a fancybox option . Any idea as to why the image still won't show when I close fancybox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code (without mentioning the syntax errors : your `src` attribute and your jQuery selectors are not properly quote closed)

1. if you bind fancybox to an element other than an anchor `<a>` then fancybox treats it as *inline* content and it will always place it back with a `display:none` property.
2. When you do

   ```
   $(document).ready(function()  {
       $('.fancybox).click(function() {
           $('.fancybox').fancybox();
       });
   });
   ```

   The first `click` on `.fancybox` selector only binds itself to fancybox but it will only fire fancybox after the second `click`

So if you want to properly bind fancybox to an element other than an anchor (a `div` in your case) and then open the image (which is inside the `div`) inside fancybox without hiding it after fancybox is closed, then you have to do:

Bind fancybox to the `div` by setting the *class* fancybox to it, not to the `img` tag

```
<div class='photo fancybox'>
    <img src='images/jpge1.jpg' />
</div>
```

Then use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').click(function () {
        var href = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        $.fancybox({
            href: href,
            type: "image"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/33d8n/)**